# How to stop while loop when having 2 inputs (char and int) in C

Tags: c

znak = character
x = number !!

If input is '-' stop, if i run this program it always asks me for 1 more input for number.

```
int X,i, sumaS=0,sumaD=0;
char znak;

printf("Char and number input:\n");




while (znak !='-'){
    scanf(" %c", &znak);
    scanf(" %d", &X);

    if (znak=='S'){
        sumaS +=X;
    }
    else{
        sumaD+=X;
    }
}
```

Test case:

S 7

D 5

S 2

S 2

D 3

D 7

-

Comment: Because you're taking input before checking the previous of whether to exit or not. You can just place a break before the second scanf

Comment: If I do that, program will stop after i input char element

Comment: Equus, what value do you think `znak` has the very first time `while (znak !='-'){` is executed?

Comment: Can i put random char in znak to check value for the first time, and then i can use scanf and my inputs?

Comment: How about ending when there is no number input on a line? For that you would however have to drop your (anyway unwise) habit of ignoring the return value of scanf().

Answer (score -1):

How about initializing znak to zero at the beginning ? (It is better for avoiding problems sometimes.
Try in the scanf() to use it without space.
use scanf("%c", &znack) instead of scanf(" %c", &znack).
(Don’t foger to use fflush(stdin) for cleaning the input buffer between 2 iterations for avoiding to get the \n in znack)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: So he can use fseek() instead